# Android Studio Method doc for jar file

Tags: android-studio

I created a jar file using android studio exposing some methods and using the jar file in another android project.
For accessing any method when I type the first letter of method, the Android Studio intelliSense shows me different option of method names along with the parameters expected by these methods.
The parameters names that appear are (String s1, String s2) and so on instead of original parameters like (String Name, String Address) which does not gives a proper meaning.
What can I do to change this behavior?